# Segues between gameScene.sks

Tags: swift, sprite-kit

I'm beginner in `Swift` and `SpriteKit`.
I have `gameViewController` with code:

```
if let scene = IntroScene(fileNamed:"IntroScene") {
        // Configure the view.
        let skView = self.view as! SKView
        skView.showsFPS = true
        skView.showsNodeCount = true
        skView.ignoresSiblingOrder = true
        scene.scaleMode = .AspectFill
        skView.presentScene(scene)
    }
}
```

My app starting with this scene. I have some code with simple animation for this scene in other viewController:

```
let introAnimationFadeIn = SKAction.fadeInWithDuration(0.05)
let introAnimation = SKAction.animateWithTextures([introAnimation1, introAnimation2, introAnimation3, introAnimation4, introAnimation5], timePerFrame: 1.5)
let sequenceIntroAnimation = SKAction.sequence([
        introAnimationFadeIn,
        introAnimation])
intro.runAction(sequenceIntroAnimation)
```

1. How I can create segue to other `GameScene` after animation complete?
2. I want to create main menu in my project. Can I create segue to other `GameScene`, when `SKSpriteNode` touched? Or create button would be better?
   I know that segue can be only with `viewControllers`, but I don't know how names segues between game scenes correct. And sorry for my English.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to go from one scene to another, you don't use segues. Segues are transitions between view controllers, not `SKScene`s.

To present another scene, just get an `SKView` and call `presentScene`!

```
let scene = YourSceneClass(fileNamed:"Name of your scene that is going to present")!
view.presentScene(scene) // view is an SKView
```

And it seems like you want to do an animation before presenting the scene. You don't need `SKAction`s for this. Why not use `SKTransition` instead?

You can use this code to transition to another scene with fade:

```
// again, view is an SKView
view.presentScene(scene, transition: SKTransition.fadeWithDuration(1))
```

Easy as that!